# Composing optional Aeson parsers

Tags: haskell, monads, composition, parsec, aeson

Here is a part of JSON object which represents the user:

```
{ "image": { "url": "http://example.com" } }
```

I need to parse it into a `User` type:

```
data User = User { imgUrl :: Maybe Text }
```

The naive solution:

```
parseJSON (Object o) = User <$> getImgUrl o
    where getImgUrl o = (o .:? "image") >>= maybe (return Nothing) (.:? "url")
```

But that's not much better than these chains:

```
case f m1 of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just m2 -> case f2 m2 of
        Nothing -> Nothing
        Just m3 -> case f3 m3 ....
```

that are often demonstrated in 'Why do you need a Monad' explanations

Thus, I need to compose parsers which look like `(.:? "url") :: Parser (Maybe a)`

I've tried to describe that composition with `comp` function:

```
getImgUrl :: Object -> Parser (Maybe Text)
getImgUrl o = o .:? "image" >>= comp (o .:? "url")

comp :: (Monad m) => (a -> m (Maybe b)) -> Maybe a -> m (Maybe b)
comp p Nothing = return Nothing
comp p (Just o) = p o
```

Smells like a Functor, but `fmap` didn't help me.

Then I decided, that composition must go on:

```
getImgUrl :: Object -> Parser (Maybe Text)
getImgUrl = comp2 (.:? "image") (.:? "url") o

-- Maybe should be changed to a matching typeclass
comp2 :: (Monad m) => (a -> m (Maybe b)) -> (b -> m (Maybe c)) -> a -> m (Maybe c)
comp2 = undefined
```

Hoogle search didn't help me, but skimming through `Control.Monad` docs gave me Kliesli composition, which I am not experienced with. I see some similarity:

```
(>=>) :: Monad m => (a -> m    b)  -> (b -> m c)     -> a -> m    c
comp2 :: Monad m => (a -> m (f b)) -> (b -> m (f c)) -> a -> m (f c)
```

The difference is that during the composition `Maybe` should be 'unwrapped'.

It seems that I am close to the solution, but still can't find it. Please give me some insight.

**[Update]:**
I've decided that the best solution to the actual problem, would be to preserve the original JSON structure and to have a nested User type:

```
data User = User { image :: Maybe Image }
data Image = Image { url :: Text }
```

This completely eliminates my problem, and makes API more compatible with the original source.

However, just for theoretical purposes, it would be great to see how the original problem could be solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was pointed to a nice solution

To start with, here is how we can do it.

```
parseJSON (Object o) = User . join <$> (traverse (.:? "url") =<< (o .:? "image"))
```

Here, we get `Parser (Maybe Object)` and pass it to the next monadic action, which works with `Maybe Object`. With the help of `traverse` we perform the action if it was Just. In the result we get `Parser (Maybe (Maybe Object)). What's left is to`join`that result and get`Parser (Maybe Object)`.

However it would be nice to make it simpler to use. I would take this operator from @bheklilr's answer and will adopt it to this solution.

```
-- The type can be much more generic, but for simplicity I would keep it in domain of the problem
(.:?>) :: FromJSON a => Parser (Maybe Object) -> Text -> Parser (Maybe a)
maybeParser .:?> key = fmap join . traverse (.:? key) =<< maybeParser
```

And after that we can use that operator to parse long chains of optional fields.

```
getImgUrl :: A.Object -> Parser (Maybe Text)
getImgUrl o = o .:? "image" .:?> "url" .:?> "foo" .:?> "bar"
```

From practical point of view, this solution is not much more useful than @bheklilr's solution and my initial 'naive' code sample. However, I like it much more because instead of matching on `Just/Nothing` it can transform many other types (e.g. `Either`)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make a relatively simple combinator based off your `>>= maybe (return Nothing) (.:? key)` pattern that should greatly simplify what you want to do:

```
(/?) :: FromJSON a => Parser (Maybe Object) -> Text -> Parser (Maybe a)
maybeParser /? key = maybeParser >>= maybe (return Nothing) (.:? key)
```

This can be used to chain together an arbitrary number of levels through a JSON document:

```
instance FromJSON User where
    parseJSON (Object o) = User <$> o .:? "image" /? "url"
    parseJSON _ = mzero

> decode "{\"image\": {\"url\": \"foobarbaz\"}}" :: Maybe User
Just (User {imgUrl = Just "foobarbaz"})
```

Another example:

```
data Test = Test (Maybe Int) deriving (Eq, Show)

instance FromJSON Test where
    parseJSON (Object o) = Test <$> o .:? "foo" /? "bar" /? "baz" /? "qux"
    parseJSON _ = mzero

> decode "{\"foo\": {\"bar\": {\"baz\": {\"qux\": 123}}}}" :: Maybe Test
Just (Test (Just 123))
```

This might not be exactly what you're looking for, but I think it solves your immediate problem.  Considering it's a 1 line function with very low complexity it seem pretty idiomatic to me.  I don't think higher levels of abstraction are really needed in this instance.

Comment: This seems to be a reasonable solution for the actual problem. However, it would be even greater to see some mind-blowing generic combinator. If no one would suggest such, in the reasonable time, I'll mark your answer.

Comment: Also, see my update above. About more proper solution that I took.

Comment: @zudov obviously using a nested data structure eliminates this problem, but I certainly have instances where this isn't as practical. For the case where you need to traverse a tree that may or may not be there an operator like the one above is very useful. There may be some combinator available from a lens library for aeson that could be of use here too.

Comment: I see, it can be aplicable in such case, but for parsing a tree it might be better to simply take a HashMap and convert it to desired representation. aeson-lens indeed solves the problem, but unfortunately I wasn't able to use lenses for my problem. You can see a code-sample here http://forum.ruhaskell.org/t/kompozicziya-vlozhennyh-opczionalnyh-json-parserov-aes/79/2?u=zudov

Comment: ``fmap Test $ o .: "foo" >>= (.: "bar") >>= (.: "baz") >>= (.: "qux")`` works "out of the box", special combinator is not needed!

Comment: But it would fail, wouldn't it?

Comment: @zudov It should fail with `mzero`, meaning your JSON will decode to `Nothing :: Maybe User`.

Comment: Well, in the real case User would have many other fields, and I don't want the User be Nothing just because the "foo" field failed to decode.

Comment: @bheklilr Take a look at my solution